# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras_preprocessing'

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conda, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to implement YOLO3 object detection using tensorflow 2.0 on google colab : https://github.com/theAIGuysCode/Object-Detection-API

And for this particular line:

```
!python3 /content/Object-Detection-API/load_weights.py
```

I'm facing this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras_preprocessing'
```

I tried installing 'keras_preprocessing' using this command:

```
!conda install keras_preprocessing
```

and then I'm facing this error:

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - keras_preprocessing

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Please help me solve the same!
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Anaconda repository of the [Keras Preprocessing](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/keras-preprocessing) package, you can install it with

```
conda install -c conda-forge keras-preprocessing
```

that is, with an `-` instead of `_` and with selecting the `conda-forge` channel.

Comment: Appreciate your help!

Comment: Did this fix your problem? I too have the same ModuleNotFoundError in a different context, but `keras-preprocessing` was already installed. Because of the `-` versus `_`, it looks like it is searching for the wrong thing, perhaps because I/we have configured something wrong...

Comment: My problem seems to be that I did not install cuDNN despite downloading it. After the install, the problem went away...

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
pip install Keras-Preprocessing
```

Comment: to use it in colab, run `!pip install Keras-Preprocessing`

Answer (score 0):

Use `from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator`

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?