# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras_preprocessing' tensorflow2.2 with pip

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I'm trying to build **tensorflow 2.2** from source with the command:
`bazel build -c opt --copt=-mavx --copt=-mavx2 --copt=-mfma --copt=-msse4.2 --action_env PYTHON_BIN_PATH=/usr/bin/python3.8  //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`

If I build the package I get the error:

```sh
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras_preprocessing'
```

However, I have **Keras-Preprocessing 1.1.0*** installed, which should be a correct version.

I know this question is similar to:
[ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras_preprocessing'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64102020/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-keras-preprocessing)
but I am, using pip and not conda. How can this be solved with pip?

This is the stacktrace:

```
/home/brent/.cache/bazel/_bazel_brent/f717514c870df2340554ff84ed4b3c4d/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/python/keras/api/create_tensorflow.python_api_keras_python_api_gen_compat_v1.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/ops/random_ops.py:285: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  minval_is_zero = minval is 0  # pylint: disable=literal-comparison
/home/brent/.cache/bazel/_bazel_brent/f717514c870df2340554ff84ed4b3c4d/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/python/keras/api/create_tensorflow.python_api_keras_python_api_gen_compat_v1.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/ops/random_ops.py:286: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  maxval_is_one = maxval is 1  # pylint: disable=literal-comparison
/home/brent/.cache/bazel/_bazel_brent/f717514c870df2340554ff84ed4b3c4d/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/python/keras/api/create_tensorflow.python_api_keras_python_api_gen_compat_v1.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/ops/ragged/ragged_batch_gather_with_default_op.py:84: SyntaxWarning: "is not" with a literal. Did you mean "!="?
  if (default_value.shape.ndims is not 0
/home/brent/.cache/bazel/_bazel_brent/f717514c870df2340554ff84ed4b3c4d/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/python/keras/api/create_tensorflow.python_api_keras_python_api_gen_compat_v1.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/ops/ragged/ragged_batch_gather_with_default_op.py:85: SyntaxWarning: "is not" with a literal. Did you mean "!="?
  and default_value.shape.ndims is not 1):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/brent/.cache/bazel/_bazel_brent/f717514c870df2340554ff84ed4b3c4d/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/python/keras/api/create_tensorflow.python_api_keras_python_api_gen_compat_v1.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/tools/api/generator/create_python_api.py", line 776, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/brent/.cache/bazel/_bazel_brent/f717514c870df2340554ff84ed4b3c4d/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/python/keras/api/create_tensorflow.python_api_keras_python_api_gen_compat_v1.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/tools/api/generator/create_python_api.py", line 755, in main
    importlib.import_module(package)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/brent/.cache/bazel/_bazel_brent/f717514c870df2340554ff84ed4b3c4d/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/python/keras/api/create_tensorflow.python_api_keras_python_api_gen_compat_v1.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/keras/datasets/imdb.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.sequence import _remove_long_seq
  File "/home/brent/.cache/bazel/_bazel_brent/f717514c870df2340554ff84ed4b3c4d/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/python/keras/api/create_tensorflow.python_api_keras_python_api_gen_compat_v1.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/keras/preprocessing/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import keras_preprocessing
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras_preprocessing'
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
ERROR: /home/brent/Documents/Projects/BenchmarkRCStrategiesSOTA/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/tools/BUILD:82:1 Executing genrule //tensorflow/python/keras/api:keras_python_api_gen failed (Exit 1)
INFO: Elapsed time: 14402.619s, Critical Path: 406.14s
INFO: 14101 processes: 14101 local.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

Comment: Could you give the detail of the building command ? If possible with the stacktrace ? Are you sure you are in the same python virtual environment ?

Comment: maybe use `python3.8 -m pip install ...` to make sure it install module in correct Python. You could also check what version shows `pip -V` and if you have `pip3.8`

Answer (score 0):

ok, my guess is that **/usr/bin/python3.8** is not the python environment in which you installed **keras-preprocessing**.

You should reinstall it with pip install and then print the path to your python environment with the command: `which python`

Then, relaunch the `bazel build` with the path of your python environment in :`PYTHON_BIN_PATH=<result of the which python command>`

Comment: Thanks, it does something, but now i get this error:`Executing genrule @local_config_python//:numpy_include failed (Exit 1)`?  Because of this:`venv_temp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/.doxyfile': No such file or directory`.